# Rounding errors with floats in Python using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, rounding-error

I'm having an issue that I believe has to do with working with floats and precision but I'm not very well versed in the various intricacies involved.  I'm a math person and in my mind I might as well still be just working with decimals on a chalkboard.  I'll begin studying up on this, but in the mean time, I'm wondering if there are any general techniques for working with floats that might address the problem I'll outline below.

I have a numpy array of decimals that I would like to round to the nearest .02.  I originally accomplished this by dividing every element of the array by .02, rounding the result, then multiplying by .02 again.  The actual data is generated by some code that process an input, but this demonstrates the problem:

```
x = np.array([.45632, .69722, .40692])
xx = np.round(x/.02)*.02
```

It seems to round everything correctly, as I can check:

```
xx
array([0.46, 0.7, 0.4])
```

However, if I inspect the first and second element, I get:

```
xx[0]
0.46000000000000002
xx[1]
0.70000000000000007
```

Each element in the array is of type numpy.float64.  The problem occurs later because I involve these numbers with comparison operators to select subsets of the data and what happens then is a little unpredictable:

```
xx[0] == .46
True
```

But,

```
xx[1] == .70
False
```

As I said, I have a work around for this particular application, but I'm wondering if anyone has a way to make my first approach work or if there are techniques for dealing with these types of numbers that are more general that I should be aware of.

Comment: You should probably compare floats without the == operator. Instead, compare the number to a range of values, like "`xx[0]` is within 1e-10 of 0.46?". Or, just don't use floats (save each number as 100x what it actually is).

Comment: hava a look at isclose or allclose in (numpy)[http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html].

Comment: Obligatory link: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using `==` to select subsets of data, try using [numpy.isclose()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html). This allows you to specify a relative/absolute tolerance for your comparison `(absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b)))`

Comment: I was actually going to answer my own question and suggest a tolerable difference and the < operator, but this is a useful little function to know about.

Comment: link is broken (can't edit): https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html

Answer (score 1):

Python's `format`could be used for this too.

```
print format(xx[1], '.100f')
```

this code return actual value of `xx[1]`

ie. `xx[1] = 0.70000000000000006661338147750939242541790008544921875`

You can check these by code shown below

```
if xx[1] == 0.70000000000000006661338147750939242541790008544921875:
    print 'true'
```