# Callable variable in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, dictionary

I'm having trouble in a loop.
I have a bunch of points (a 5-D space) saved in an array

```
Coords=[]
Coords.append(zip(x,y,z,t,w))
Coords=np.array(Coords,float)
```

so that I can call all coords of 1 particle by, for example

```
Coords[0,0]=[0.0.0.0.1.]
Coords[0,1]=[0.1,0.,0.,0.,0.9]
Coords[0,1,0]=0.1
```

Now, I need to calculate some properties for every particle, so I create a dicionary, where for every key(i.e. every particle) I compute somwthing

```
A={}
Aa=np.arange(0.0,1.0+0.001,0.001)
for s in range(len(Coords[0])):
    A[s]=[]
    for a in Aa:
        if Coords[0,s,2]>=a and np.sqrt(Coords[0,s,0]*Coords[0,s,4])>=a:
            A[s].append(a)
```

Here I get the proper dictionary, so I'm calling the varaibles Coords[0,s,0] and Coords[0,s,4] properly, there is no problem.

Now, this is where I have problems.
I need to compute another property for every particle for every value in A, therefore I create a dictionary of dictionaries.

```
L={}
for s in range(len(Coords[0])):
    L[s]={}
    for a in A[s]:
        L[s][a]=[]
        for i in Aa:
            if (Coords[0,s,0]-i)*(Coords[0,s,4]-i)-a**2==0:
                L[s][a].append(i)
```

Now I have a problem. The variables Coords are not called properly, there are missig values.

For example, the Coords[0,2,0]=0.1 and Coords[0,2,4]=0.6 should produce two values in the list: 0.1 and 0.6 (for a=0). However, in the list only appears the value 0.1, like the variable  Coords[0,2,4]=0.6 doesn't exist.

However, if I write by hand the if condition like (for a=0)

```
if (0.1-i)*(0.6-i)-a**2==0
```

then I get the proper values.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is it because I have dictionaries inside dictionaries?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you use dictionaries anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second condition:

```
(Coords[0,s,0]-i)*(Coords[0,s,4]-i)-a**2==0:
```

Try using a tolerance for your comparison, something like:

```
abs((Coords[0,s,0]-i)*(Coords[0,s,4]-i)-a**2) < 10**-10
```

There's a more detailed description here:
[Rounding errors with floats in Python using Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497889/rounding-errors-with-floats-in-python-using-numpy)