# Problem with numpy the dot product does not work

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I am currently learning linear algebra and I am trying to try out what I learn in code. I am using numpy in python.

The problem is that as you know any matrix multiplied with its inverse it will give us the the identity matrix.

but here it does not happen.

```
B= np.array([[3.0, 0.0, 2.0], [2.0, 0.0, -2.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0]])
Binv = np.linalg.inv(B)
Bbits= np.dot(B,Binv)
```

I have tried it manually. It gets the inverse correctly but the dot product is not. 
See the output of Bbits

```
[[ 1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -5.55111512e-17]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: The difference is very small (1e-17), it's probably a round off error

Comment: Definitely round off error. You can check if your final matrix matches the identity matrix within some tolerance with `np.allclose`: `np.allclose(Bbits,np.eye(3))` will check if `Bbits` matches an identity matrix of the same size, `np.eye(3)` using default tolerances, see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html for how to control the tolerance.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is actually correct!

Running the exact same code you provided, but adding a `np.around()`,

```
B= np.array([[3.0, 0.0, 2.0], [2.0, 0.0, -2.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0]])
Binv = np.linalg.inv(B)
Bbits= np.around(np.dot(B,Binv),2)
```

we get the following output:

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [-0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

In your results, the -5.55111512e-17 is just a rounding error!

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was really helpful but is there any way that I can get rid of this rounding error. I don't know if it is even possible and I know that the error is really small. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes! One way is using the ```np.around()``` that I've shown. @chris gave a nice suggestion above, which is to use the ```np.allclose``` to check the tolerance. You can also use the Python's ```format```: check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497889/rounding-errors-with-floats-in-python-using-numpy